# Balance column in a HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

I'm developing a personal finance control system and I want to create a balance column similar to a Bank Statement. My data is stored in a MySQL database with the following structure:

| ID | Type | Date | Description | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | D | 01/02/2024 | Transaction 1 | 150,00 |
| 02 | D | 03/02/2024 | Transaction 2 | 250,00 |
| 03 | D | 05/02/2024 | Transaction 3 | 50,00 |
| 04 | C | 06/02/2024 | Transaction 4 | 980,00 |

I need to create a column that stores the previous balance from a query. Each row will update this column with the current balance. Here's an example (assuming that the previous balance is 250.00):

| ID | Type | Date | Description | Amount | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | D | 01/02/2024 | Transação 1 | -150,00 | 100,00 |
| 02 | D | 03/02/2024 | Transação 2 | -250,00 | -150,00 |
| 03 | D | 05/02/2024 | Transação 3 | -50,00 | -200,00 |
| 04 | C | 06/02/2024 | Transação 4 | 980,00 | 780,00 |

That's what I'm doing in PHP:

```
$transacoes = '
<table id="tabAccountDetails" class="table lms_table_active" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" hidden>#</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Balance</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
$earlierBalance= 0;
$saldo = 0;
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if ($saldoAnterior == 0) {
        $earlierBalance = $reg["EarlierBalance"];
        $balance = $reg["TransactionAmount"] + $earlierBalance ;

    } else {
        $balance = $reg["TransactionAmount"] + $balance;

    }
    $transactionId = $reg["TransactionId"];
    $account = $reg["AccountName"];
    $description = $reg["TransactionDescription"];
    $date = $reg["TransactionDate"];
    $amount = $reg["TransactionAmount"];
    
    $transacoes .= '
    <tr>
        <td>' . $transactionId . '</td>
        <th scope="row">' . $date . '</th>
        <td>' . $description . '</td>
        <td>' . number_format($ammount, 2, ",", ".") . '</td>
        <td>' . number_format($saldo, 2, ",", ".") . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
$transacoes .= '
    </tbody>
</table>';
echo $transacoes;
```

For some reason, it is not correctly updating for all rows returned from the database. This is the query I'm using to select the transactions:

```
SELECT t.TransactionId, 
        t.AccountId, 
        a.AccountName,
        DATE_FORMAT(t.TransactionDate, '%d/%m/%Y') TransactionDate, 
        t.TransactionDescription, 
        t.TransactionType,
        t.TransactionAmount,
        (select SUM(if(TransactionType = 'C', TransactionAmount, TransactionAmount*-1)) 
            FROM  tbtransactions
            WHERE UserId = $userId AND AccountId = $idConta AND TransactionDate < '$initialDate') EarlierBalance
        FROM tbtransactions t
        INNER JOIN tbaccount a ON a.AccountId = t.AccountId
        WHERE t.UserId = $userId AND t.TransactionDate BETWEEN '$initialDate' AND '$finalDate'  
        ORDER BY t.TransactionDate
```

Can somebody give me any north or help regarding the best way to do it?

Comment: I don't think this is going to cut it as a questiion and will remain closed. As this is not specific enough. Have some suggestions though. If you are trying to calulate the balance. Get rid of all the other noise and focus just on the balance. See what your query is returning for each row. place the query once and then foreach over it. i think your query is returning something weird, and maybe not looking right. Or you are resetting you balance onc each loop to tranaction amount. 
$amount = $reg["TransactionAmount"];
Shouldn't $amount = $balance? Since that's the var that's being added to?

Comment: Thanks for you consideration, but the query returns the right records. The $amount variable stores the TransactionAmount column returned from the query. The balance column that I need to creat is a dynamic colums that should sum erliear balance wiith current transaction amount. Do you know? Is it possible to reopen the post that I can give more details?